# Why is content written as text?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script that adds a link to a div in the onload and for some reason the content (images) is displayed as written html text. Why is that and how can I correct it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function AffiliateLink() {
            var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('AffiliateLink'),
                i = boxes.length;

            while (i--) {
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                var content = document.createTextNode(boxes[i].innerHTML);

                link.setAttribute('href', boxes[i].getAttribute('title'));
                link.appendChild(content);

                boxes[i].innerHTML = '';
                boxes[i].appendChild(link);
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="AffiliateLink()">

    <div class="AffiliateLink" title="http://www.google.com">Google</div>
    <div class="AffiliateLink" title="http://www.apple.com"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/black-icons-by-mike-demetriou/png/128x128/App%20apple%20logo.png"></a></div>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you think create**Text**Node does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document.createTextNode forces the HTML to be text.  Just copy one innerHTML to the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/86fWM/1/

```
    while (i--) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');

        link.setAttribute('href', boxes[i].getAttribute('title'));
        link.innerHTML = boxes[i].innerHTML;

        boxes[i].innerHTML = '';
        boxes[i].appendChild(link);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that's explicitly what a `textNode` is that you're creating, it explicitly handles everything you give it as *text* and does not interpret the HTML. If you want to set HTML content, use the `innerHTML` attribute:

```
link.innerHTML = boxes[i].innerHTML;
```

It's debatable whether you may want to simply clone or move the `boxes[i]` node instead though instead of assigning one `innerHTML` to another.

Comment: I want the same content but add the link around it. How would that be done?

Comment: To show the solution works here's a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pb8We/2/

Comment: @vsdev You can use DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/9YS5w/

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating a **text node** containing `html` tags, so they are treated as `text` and not `html`.

You can easily fix that by replacing

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
var content = document.createTextNode(boxes[i].innerHTML);

link.setAttribute('href', boxes[i].getAttribute('title'));
link.appendChild(content);
```

by

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', boxes[i].getAttribute('title'));
link.innerHTML = boxes[i].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

More then one way to the target.  the "create text node" made **text** node.  replacing it with innerHTML will make the next code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function AffiliateLink() {
                var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('AffiliateLink'),
                    i = boxes.length;

                while (i--) {
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var content = boxes[i].innerHTML;

                    a.href = boxes[i].title;
                    a.innerHTML = content;

                    boxes[i].innerHTML = '';
                    console.log (i);
                    boxes[i].appendChild(a);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="AffiliateLink()">

        <div class="AffiliateLink" title="http://www.google.com">Google</div>
        <div class="AffiliateLink" title="http://www.apple.com"><img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/black-icons-by-mike-demetriou/png/128x128/App%20apple%20logo.png"></a></div>

    </body>
</html>
```